# Could not install package 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core.UI 4.3.4.13329'.

Tags: c#, nuget-package, windows-store

When I try to install "DotNetOpenAuth" from NuGet, I get an error "Could not install package 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core.UI 4.3.4.13329'......... ".  I am developing windows 8 store app.

[image]

Comment: It seems that `DotNetOpenAuth.Core.UI` is targeting *.NET Core runtime*, which you aren't running on.

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear. You either need to change your target framework, or find an alternative.

Comment: It resolves all dependencies but not "DotNetOpenAuth.Core.UI" , I tried to install it separately but it won't work. What should I do?   ....  Yuval Itzchakov ....